# Laravel: Using different queue types in one application

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel loads queue provider depends on the configuration you point. It means that all jobs can go to only one type of queues. Depends of job type I want to send it to sqs queue or to sync queue. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

In your Queue configuration file:

```
'default' => 'sqs-west',

'connections' => array(

'sync' => array(
    'driver' => 'sync',
),

'sqs-west' => array(
    'driver' => 'sqs',
    'key'    => 'KEY',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'queue'  => 'ADDRESS',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
),

'sqs-east' => array(
    'driver' => 'sqs',
    'key'    => 'KEY',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'queue'  => 'ADDRESS',
    'region' => 'eu-east-1,
),
```

Then you'd start Artisan working the queues with:

`php artisan queue:work --queue=sqs-east`

or

`php artisan queue:work --queue=sqs-west`

Comment: How can I dispatch jobs to different queues from code?